# ZIPX Compression Method 2048

Tags: compression, zip, lzma, winzip, bzip

I have a zipx file that is using compression method 2048.  I know that the ZIPX format uses one of four compression methods (LZMA, BZIP2, PPMd, WavPack).  The compression method number associated with each of these methods is:

- LZMA (14)
- BZIP2 (12)
- PPMd (98)
- WavPack (97)

Does someone understand what compression method 2048 stands for (name)?  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

According to http://kb.winzip.com/kb/entry/7, the compression method types are below so my guess is that it refers to Jpeg.

•   BZip
•   LZMA
•   PPMd
•   Jpeg*
•   Wavpack*